# I have created a logo similar to an existing one. Is it plagiarism?

Tags: logo, legal

I have designed a logo for my friends company and just now have found a similar one existing in real. I feel very bad about that, what should I do? Redesign or not?

I have made all needed research in order to make violet logo according to companies values.

[image]
[image]

Comment: out of curiosity, which one is yours, and which one is the established logo?

Comment: Coincidences happen, and this may very well be one, but yea, these are way to close. I'd redesign.

Comment: My one is on the left. I believe that I will try to change it. Don't fell very well about the situation :)

Comment: this can only improve your skills :)

Answer (score 3):

I am sorry to say this, but you should redesign it. I mean it is identical.
As a designer, it is your duty to push forward new and innovative. These things happen sometimes but it is our job to minimize such coincidences.

Answer (score 3):

They're very similar.  I would say take some time to sketch out something new.  even if you start with this, start playing with the forms involved for a couple hours and see where it takes you.

If you're really stuck, I'd suggest maybe checking out a couple skillshare classes on logo making.  I'm not suggesting this for any other reason other than a change of mindset and maybe some inspiration.

Another idea might be to just start from scratch with some moodboarding and see if you can come up with something original.

Comment: Just thinking - you may be able to retain some of the feel and still set this logo apart.  There's tons of examples of very similar logos out there, but I do think that your prime motivation (while still servicing the need of the client) is to set yourself apart :)

Answer (score 3):

If this is just coincidence, it's fair too similar.
As I understand, you are making logo for Lithuanian AD agency based in Vilnius "A Lygio Reklama" that even don't have website so far.

The similar logo was made by Freytag Anderson for [Little Black Book, London based online creative resource](http://www.lbbonline.com/) (I would call it blog). The current identity for LBB [was launched in 2012](http://bpando.org/2012/02/24/branding-little-black-book/), so it's at least 3 years before you published your work.

I don't like LBB logo. In my opinion it's representing big book and small B letter, not a little book. But what is done, is done.

But your logo is even more senseless. The name of the company is "A Lygio Reklama" means "A Level Advertising" (if Google is correct). And there is no connection in your work with "A level" at all. It's barely possible to find any connection with advertising (if we don't count visual connection with LBB logo).

Because of all of that you definitely should redesign this work.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely re-design it.  Nobody in the world would believe that it wasn't an intentional copying, even though in fact it wasn't.